# Create PHP friendly array for checkboxes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, forms

The title of the question might not be very explaining and I would really appreciate anyone who can help me with a solution. It's a special case where I have no access to the PHP file and can't change anything there and I need another solution which I really couldn't find anywhere.

**Here is my question:**
I have a `form` with a `hidden` value:

```
<form id="myForm" action="" method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" name="colors[]" value="">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I also have created an `array` create with `javascript` with some values:

```
<script>
  var myArray = new Array();
  myArray.push('red');
  myArray.push('yellow');
  myArray.push('green');
</script>
```

I then have a random `button` somewhere no the page(doesn't really matter where)

```
<button id="myButton">Add to hidden array</button>
```

So the thing I wanna do is, that when I click the button `id="myButton"`, I want a `jQuery` solution to add all elements from the `myArray` array to the hidden field `name="colors[]"`.
I know the solution to add them as `JSON` `string` to the value of the `hidden` field and then use `json_decode` in my `PHP` file to read the `array`. But the thing is that I have no access to the `PHP` file and can't change previously written functions and logic. The `PHP` file receives an `array` of `checkboxes` as it's usually done in the standard way like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="green">
<input type="checkbox name="colors[]" value="red">
<input type="checkbox name="colors[]" value="yellow">
```

Is there a way to put `myArray` in the colors[] array of the `hidden input` field without using JSON strings and without needing to change anything in the PHP file, so that PHP receives and processes the field `colors` as a normal `array` of `checkboxes`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add multiple hidden inputs to the form, each with a different value from the array.

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    $("#myForm [name='colors[]']").remove();
    $.each(myArray, function() {
        $("#myForm").append($("<input>", {
            type: "hidden",
            name: "colors[]",
            value: this
        }));
    });
});
```